# Can bootstrap carousel slides be arbitrary HTML elements or does it require images?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

According to the bootstrap website a carousel is:

```
A slideshow component for cycling through elements, like a carousel.
```

However in every example I see the slides contain an image. My attempts to create slides which are simply html markup don't seem to work.  Is this simply because the slides are intended to be images with captions and the above documentation is too vague?

Basically what I'm trying to do is display subsets of records retrieved from the server using tables. I don't really have any way of fetching subsets of the records from the server. I know how to do this with tabs, but with potentially 1000 records there might be too many tabs.

Edit: I got it working with the carousel thanks to everyones help, however it turned out that using a carousel wasn't good UX for what I was trying to accomplish.  Turned out pagination with a single javascript function to manipulate the "hidden" class of table rows was a much better solution.

I have a working jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/wipexelara/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Do the elements you intend to scroll through have fixed widths?

Comment: are you just want to have html-interpreted text in the carousel?, its possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it, very easy and clearÖ

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item  >p ,
  .carousel-inner > .item > p {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <p>HALLO</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <p>HALLO2</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <p>HALLO3</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <p>HALLO4</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a way to have HTML inside the Carousel. Under the `Getting Started` section on Bootstrap's Website, there are examples you can use to get yourself started. Try using this one:

[Bootstrap Carousel Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)

See the below Code Snippet for everything you need to achieve this functionality.

Hope that helps!

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

        <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAGZmZgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAFVVVQAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->


        <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

        <div class="container marketing">

            <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->


            <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>

        </div><!-- /.container -->


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```